# Is there a word for the opposite of being hollow?

Tags: adjectives, antonyms

I'm looking for an adjective that describes an object that, rather than is just the *outside*, is instead just the *inside*.

Searching for antonyms of *hollow*, I have only found the word *solid*, which suggests both the inside *and* outside of an object.

I really need a way to describe something as being *just* the inside of something.

I can only think of words like *core* or *heart* to describe what I'm looking for, but those are nouns.

> When a tree has only its exterior, the tree is hollow. It is a hollow tree.
>
> When a tree has only its interior, the tree is _____. It is a _____ tree.

---

Perhaps tree was a bad example, it was the only object I could think of at the time that made sense to be a hollow object. Any object where that description could apply is a reasonable substitute, it does not have to be specifically about a tree.

Comment: Is it a mathematically graphical/topological tree or an actual biological tree?

Comment: The difficulty I'm having is no real-world tree can exist that is without an exterior, or bark? Can you give another example?

Comment: Any core still has an outside. A core without an outside is a geometrical point, i.e. a purely theoretical concept devoid of any body.

Comment: **interiority** *noun*: the quality of being interior or inward. • inner character or nature; subjectivity.

Comment: What we see, we perceive to be the exterior. If you peel a couple of layers off an onion, what you've got is some onion peels and the rest of the, wait for it, onion.

Comment: **substantive** *adjective*: 4. Of or relating to the essence or substance; essential; 5.  Having a solid basis; firm.

Comment: I would say the tree is naked.

Comment: I thought this was going to be something more metaphorical, like 'superficial'. The opposite there is 'still waters run deep'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I nominate [skeleton](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/skeleton).

> The supporting framework, basic structure, or essential part of
>   something:
>
> *the concrete skeleton of an unfinished building* (No exterior)
>
> *the skeleton of a report* (No exterior)

[From Oxford]

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a tree, I might use the term **denuded**.

> **denuded** *adj*
>    without the natural or usual covering;

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/denuded)

By the way, this is not really an antonym of hollow, because what you're looking for is not really an antonym, per se. It's more like a mirrored state, or a complementary state. The antonym of hollow would be *filled* or *full* or any of several others. The state you describe is something else again.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that you have the ***core*** or ***heart*** of something.

Answer (score 1):

*Exfoliated*

> 1. To remove (a layer of bark or skin, for example) in flakes or scales; peel.
> 2. To cast off in scales, flakes, or splinters.

...if the exterior has been removed by some process.

[FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exfoliate)

Comment: What does this have to do with not being hollow?

Comment: Nothing, but it seems that 'not hollow' isn't exactly what OP is looking for.

Comment: Clever approach, user! But it doesn't conjure the image in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the word you are looking for is *marrow*. However, I don't know if it suits the example you gave. I'd rather say *naked* or *bare*.

Comment: Could you add a definition of that as a adjective, or an example? It's along the lines of what I'm looking for in terms of the innards of a bone, but on searching I can only find descriptions of the vegetable.

Comment: The problem is that "marrow" is not an adjective, it’s a noun. It means the inmost or essential part. "bone marrow" also means the soft fatty vascular tissue in the cavities of bones: a major site of blood cell production. Example: Pierce to the marrow of a problem. I guess "marrowy" is the adjective form of it, but I don't know if it still has the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with **skinned**, the past participle of "to skin", which is defined by oxforddictionaries.com as to "remove the skin from (an animal or a fruit or vegetable)".  Similar words might be "stripped", or, less pleasantly, "flayed".